# Android code to accept name and phone number & save it on tapping accept button

Tags: android, save, contacts

Can someone suggest code to accept name and number save it?? my layout is as follows.

**

```
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Contact Name" android:id="@+id/TextView01"    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:contentDescription="Name" android:cursorVisible="true" android:gravity="center" android:editable="true">
    </TextView>
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TableRow>
    <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>      
 <TextView android:text="Phone Number" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:phoneNumber="true" android:gravity="center">
 </TextView>
    <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/EditText02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>
 <Button android:text="Accept" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:gravity="center">
 </Button>
```

**

plz suggest how I should proceed from here.

Comment: Do you have an `Activity` that loads  this layout?  Do you have any code?

Comment: no i dont!!! this is code ive.
**package com.Myapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Myappact extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to get the data :

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    EditText nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    EditText phoneText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
    String name = nameText.getText();
    String phone = phoneText.getText();
    // Save the values, send to server yada yada
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an onClickListener to a save button. And inside the listener grab the values inside the editText boxes where people wrote in there name and phone number. Do a check to see if the name and number are valid. (As in not left blank). Then insert the values into an SQLite database.

Button onClick example: 
http://android-helper.blogspot.ca/2011/04/android-simple-button-click-example.html

Save to SQLite example:
http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/how-to-insert-data-in-to-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

Comment: how do i create a database for this particular application using MS SQL server management studio express?

Comment: ive created a database with table contacts having 2colums name n phone number now how do i link it to my android code so that info is saved to the database ?